# Javascript - Global scope or local scope, not able to figure it out

Tags: javascript

I am not able to figure it out if d is a global variable or because of (,) it will have a local scope like a b c?

I think a , b and c have local scope and d is having a local scope.

```
function something(param) {
    var a, b, c= {
            someNumber: 7,
            someObject: {},
        },
        d= {}
}
```

Comment: It's scoped to your function.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that `d` is local. It would be global if you would have used `;` rather than `,` after `c`.

Comment: However, one thing to be mindful of is something like this: `var a, b, c = d = {}, e = {}`. In this case, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `e` are scoped to the function. `d`, however, is global.

Comment: You could have a look at the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem which could be answered with a trivial experiment.

Comment: Thanks everyone for support, i learn by asking, by reading it becomes monotonus

Comment: You should learn by reading and experimenting. If you need to ask a trivial question then ask the guy next to you. SO is designed for interesting programming problems the answers to which can serve as a valuable resource for programmers in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` is local, because the comma keeps it part of the `var` statement.

Comment: Thanks scimonster, i have just started learning javascript, and i want experts to guide me, that is why i am asking from you people :)

Answer (score 1):

You can theorize all you want, but nothing beats [solving it walking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvitur_ambulando):

```
function something(param) {
    var a, b, c= {
            someNumber: 7,
            someObject: {},
        },
        d= {}
}

something()
console.log(d);
```

produces:

> ReferenceError: d is not defined

Comment: It is coming undefined for each and every variable

Comment: Yes, because they're all local.